# What is the best way to secure UDP server with HMAC?

Tags: python, ssl, udp

I hope this is not too opinionated because I'm looking for a finite answer.

I'm developing a UDP server in Python 3.x that is utilizing asyncio. The server is going to work with a game engine to process pretty much every interaction a player makes in the game. Therefore, I have to authenticate the game client with the game server in some way as well ensure replay attacks do not happen on top of everything else that could harm or spoof the game server.

When it comes to authenticating with UDP, I'm at a loss. My plan is to have both the game client and game server authenticate per user and game session. That means having something like a public key on the client end and a private key on the server end where the server can authenticate the client is approved.

During that authentication, I am going to generate a symmetric key that the game server makes and passes it down to the game client so every packet sent can be verified with that symmetric key using HMAC. If not, all packets are dropped.

**My Question**

Is this the best approach? Creating some type of public key where something like a token is generated per session to ensure packets coming to the UDP server are from authenticated clients? My worry here is the keys are still stored in a Windows EXE file and still likely can be cracked and extracted or am I just too paranoid?

Comment: Hmm, doesn't *SSL* / *TLS*  protocol involve a connection?

Comment: Any solution like this is easy to crack if people are motivated. Look at the example of RTMPE streams: Flash Media Server would reject anything that couldn't authenticate as a Flash Player, but as soon as there was some value in spoofing a Flash Player (to pirate streams off sites like Hulu), people immediately figured out how to do it (first by just replaying the stream from Flash, but soon after by extracting the key).

Comment: If you're willing to get into an arms race, finding new ways to obfuscate the key hiding and handshaking after each crack—together with heuristics to detect hacked clients in other ways, and aggressively banning people who get caught—this could be practical (assuming the value is high enough), but it won't be easy.

Comment: I think most games that go down this road tie it into their anti-piracy authentication—if each user already has a unique key, which has to pass an auth algorithm on the client and is also stored on the server (and may be bound to a particular machine), then you have something else you can scramble into the handshake, and now you only have to stay ahead on at least one of the two arms races at a time.

Comment: @CristiFati You can build something parallel to TLS on top of UDP and your own out-of-band connection management. In fact, SIP already did that, and you could probably just borrow DTLS (if you're happy with its notion of connections. But (D)TLS doesn't solve the OP's problem. It's meant to prevent people from accidentally connecting to spoofed servers, or being MitM'd; it doesn't prevent people from intentionally connecting with spoofed clients (or even have a notion of them—the public key that goes with a cert is meant to be easily retrievable by anyone).

Comment: Exactly @abarnert Thanks for clarifying that. My worry is mostly a player creating a spoofed client that fools the server in order to game the system on top of other issues like a player editing the memory address of the game client to fabricate values that can be sent to the server from the non-spoofed client.

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer my own question!

**No It's Not The Best Approach**

The reason this is not the best approach is because even with this process, my use of public/private key was incorrect. I was not referring to encrypting data between the client and server, I was referring to creating a nonce with having some type of password on the client that matches the password on the server.

This means the moment I send credentials from the client to the server, it's being sent without encryption on the line or in the buffer to the server. Once this authentication is accepted by the server, it will hash the password, store it and then send the nonce back to the client, which will also be without encryption.

The username, the password, and the nonce will be vulnerable to Man in the Middle attacks from both a third-party and the client itself. Which means they can sniff the packets, snag the transmission and crack the user or attempt replays being they have the nonce.

**Solution**

My game client does not have SSL/TSL/DTSL options. This is why I actually posted the question, but did not clarify this. My server, as it's custom within Python, does have that ability though. But, I found a plugin for the game engine last night that allows for AES encryption of the data being written to the buffer before said buffer is sent as a packet to the UDP server, which means I can encrypt the passing of data in those packets in a secure way that hopefully the server can decrypt with a legit private key.

Doing this will be a good option because it likely will be my only option. Now when a malicious user sniffs the traffic, they wont be able to see credentials or the nonce. The only issue after that is cracking the EXE, which I'm fine with for now.

Comment: Encrypt does not provides integrity, you can change the ciphertext and the receive sill not have any clue about the change. Some encryption algorism (like AES-GCM, AES-Poly1305) can provide integrity, because of course it have a MAC.